# Embedding .Net Framework setup executable in WIX bootstrapper

Tags: .net, frameworks, wix, bootstrapper

Is there some way to embed the .Net framework redist exe (dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe) inside my wix bootstrapper "Sedtup.exe"?

My feature MSI is allready embedded in the Setup.exe.
I would like to deploy a single setup exe with the .Net framework embedded if possible as apposed to providing the .Net setup alongside the bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrapper, use `Compressed="yes"` on the `ExePackage` as in:

```
<ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" InstallCommand="/q"
              SourceFile="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
              DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)"
              />
```

If you the bootstrapper to download the package from the web, you need to specify the `DownloadUrl` attribute (note the package still has to be on your local machine at compile time):

```
DownloadUrl="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164193"
```

Comment: Weird.  On my machine it was under "C:\Program Files (x86)\" is there a way to just have it automatic, rather than hard code the path? (I need to also be able to build my bootstrapper from 32-bit machines.)

Comment: Also -- is there a way to do it with the web install -- so that it doesn't add 50 mb to the main bootstrapper file?